# Hibernate returns false values on join

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

i've got error using hibernate.
My classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int cartId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;
```

My second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "article")
    private String article;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "manufacturer")
    private String manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "unitsinstock")
    private long unitsInStock;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Cart cart;
```

When I execute this code:

```
String hql = "SELECT c FROM Cart c JOIN c.product ORDER BY c.cartId ASC";
List<Cart> cart = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

**It returns such false values where product_id equals cart_id**

I saw this after transferring my database to new pc (postgres 9.5 using pg_dump).

I thought it was some errors after restoring, but tables structures are correct.

cart foreign key: `"cart_pkey" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

product index: `"products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (product_id)`

product primary key: `TABLE "cart" CONSTRAINT "cart_pkey" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

your hql is not clear to me , what are you trying to return , if cart why you even need to join?

The right hql would be

```
     String hql = "SELECT c.product FROM Cart c ORDER BY c.cartId ASC";
     List<product> cart = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

in this way you get cart objects which already have reference to product, no need for anything else

Comment: I want to return e.g. all information about cart of user with id == N, to return this i need all information about product (name, price, ... ) to do this i use inner join=)

Comment: I edited the answer , is that what you are trying to get?

Comment: Nope) it worked fine with my hql `SELECT c FROM Cart c JOIN c.product ORDER BY c.cartId ASC`. It's not problem in hql. Main problem is that after database dump/restoring **this query returns list where cart_id == product_id in product ref**. e.g. i've got record like cart_id: 10, user_id: 13, product_id: 21, quantity: 23. This should return cart with this values and cart.product with product_id = 21 and data about product with id = 21, query returns cart properly (cart_id:10, user_id: 12, product_id:21, quantity: 23), but cart.product return product with id 10 and all data of 10th product.

Comment: I edited my answer , the HQL i shared will definitly get what you are asking for

Comment: it returns same output. Some "connection" between cart_id and product_id. They're equals.